# Remove all duplicates from a list in scheme

Tags: scheme

Write a SCHEME function remove-duplicates that removes all duplicates from a list. (Hint: you might start by defining a function which removes all duplicates of a particular given value v from a list; then what?)

Example:

> (remove-duplicates ’(1 2 3 4 5 3 1)) should produce 
>   ’(1 2 3 4 5)

I have this so far:

```
(define (remove v l)
  (if (null? l)
      l
      (if (equal? v (car l))
          (cdr l)
          (cons (car l)
                (remove v (cdr l))))))

(define (remove-duplicates l)
  (cond ((null? l) '())
        ((null? (cdr l)) l)
        ((equal? (car l) (car (cdr l)))
         (remove (cdr (cdr l)) (remove-duplicates (cdr (cdr l)))))
        (else (cons (car l) (remove-duplicates (cdr l))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of abstraction is that you can have simpler code that does some of the job which is testable. Have you tested `remove` on its own?

```
(remove 'a '(g a b c a b c a))
; ==> (g b c a b c a)
```

So when it find one match the rest of the list is `(cdr l)`. Are you just expecting one duplicate? This is the most important part of your solution.

When it comes to `remove-duplicates` you do too much. When the list is not empty the first element is the first element of the result consed with the recursion with the argument being the rest of argument with the first element removed. ie. `(cons (car l) (remove-duplicates (remove (car l) (cdr l))`. No more comparing necessary.